# Style HTML Form in CSS File

Tags: html, css, forms, styles

Context: I am making a web page where the user enters data such as the time to open the curtain and with my Raspberry Pi 3 and ESP8266 and Motors it will open the curtain based on that time given, this is not the problem. I have a html file, and a CSS file which styles the HTML.

So the question is, **"How would I style my form in HTML from my CSS File" and if so, how can I style particular forms rather than all forms.**

```html
<html>
<body>
<form action ="." method="POST">
<br>Time to open curtain: </br>
<input type="text" name="CurtainOpenTime" placeholder="Default Open Time: 8am">
<input type="submit" name="SubmitCurtainTimes" value="Execute">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html

Comment: You should follow a `HTML` and `CSS` tutorial instead of asking here ... https://w3schools.com is a good place to start

Comment: Yes I went to w3schools.com first and they used other methods but the answer provided in this stackoverflow thread was the most simplistic and understandable. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By giving it a class.

**in CSS**

```
.my_form
{
    color: #f00;
}
```

**in HTML**

```
<form class="my_form">

</form>
```

Comment: Ok that works, thank  you very much for your fast response and for the solution.

Comment: @ThePGT accept the answer if it worked for you - give 'em some good karma

Comment: I tried to but it said I had to wait 7 minutes, it says 1 minute now so I'll do it in a minute.

Answer (score -1):

Each form can have a unique ID, in the example below I named it curtains. Styling of the elements is only limited by your phantasy. I've made a few examples below.

```css
.text {
  margin: 1em 0;
  color: red;
}

input[type="text"] {
height: 2em;
font-size: 2em;
}

input[type="submit"] {
height: 2em;
margin-top: 1em;
width: 6em;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
font-size: 1.5em;
border: thin solid lightblue;
border-radius: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form id="curtains" action="." method="POST">
  <div class="text">Time to open curtain:</div>
      <input type="text" name="CurtainOpenTime" placeholder="Default Open Time: 8am"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="SubmitCurtainTimes" value="Execute">
</form>
```

Comment: Styling of the elements is only limited by your phantasy? What that suppose to mean? (down vote wasn't me though)

Comment: @Gerard, Yes I did find that but I want some more customisation by doing them individually, but thank you for your time very much I will +1 this for your time I really really appreciate it very much thank you! :)

Comment: @Red -I don't care about down votes. Just trying to help a little here. It's not a competition.

Comment: @Gerard I know you don't care about downvotes. Im just wondering what `Styling of the elements is only limited by your phantasy` means :)

Comment: Meaning you can make anything you can think of.